# Best way to systematically find the dotnet .dll that executes from "dotnet run" commands in the cli

Tags: c#, .net, neovim

I'm currently trying to automate the process of finding the .dll that will be ran for debugging in neovim. At the moment, I have a function that lets me manually specify where the .dll is that will be ran for the dap process. I am looking to automate this.

Currently, the only method I have, that can reliably do this for the ASP.net projects that I work with, is to find the `launchSettings.json` and assume that the project that contains this file also contains the path to the .dll and the name of the .dll will be `<project-assembly-name>.dll`.

This method seems to work fairly well if a repo contains a single `launchSettings.json`. But, this isn't always the case. Is there a best practice for finding this .dll? Are there any `dotnet` cli commands that could assist?

Comment: dlls should be added to project so they are in the csproj file or the json file.  Some people do not bother to add dlls to the project and just manually put into the bin folder.  A c# executable automatically looks for a dll in the same folder as the executable.  So you plan of finding dlls will not always work when dlls were not added to the project.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to the dll that is created by dotnet during the build process. This project specific dll is what is used by the ide when debugging. VS and rider understand the location and name of this dll. I'm trying to learn how they figure it out.

Comment: You main dll probably is calling child dlls.  That is why I suggested starting by looking in the bin folder.  You can also open the csproj file which is text with an editor to see what objects are being used.  The child dlls need to be in the same folder as the main dlls unless the instructions in the csproj (or config files) specify other folders.

Comment: That's the path I've been traveling down and what I was referencing when I said `<project-assembly-name>.dll`. The PropertyGroup.AssemblyName that resides in the .csproj seems to be the name that is given to the dll in question. The problem with this name, is that there are MANY msbuild macros that can be used here.

Comment: If you copy the missing file to the deploy folder does the application work?  If the dll was manually put in the bin folder than it is impossible to always find where the file originated.  The best thing to do is to place the dll in the main project folder.  Then from VS use the menu option Add Existing item and then browse for the dll.  After adding the dll in the Solution Explorer find the dll and right click.  There is an option to Copy and check the option to Copy If newer.